# Count frequency of strings in found in List2 from List1 matched in any order

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to iterate through a list of strings, (`keyword_list`) to find matches in a second list, (`target_keyword_list`) in any order and return the count.

At the moment my code only finds exact matches, but I'd like to return a match if all of the words are found in any order.

For example, the code below returns a value of 1, but I'd like it to return 3

**Minimum Reproducible Example Below**

```
keyword_list = ["nike shoes"]
target_keyword_list = ["nike shoes", "shoes nike", "nike airmax shoes"]


check_list = []
for i in keyword_list:
    check_freq = sum(i in s for s in target_keyword_list)
    check_list.append(check_freq)


print(check_list)
```

Ideally I'd like to modify the existing code if possible.

Comment: Why `keyword_list` is a list ? And not only one string ? there could be more ?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to understand the minimum reproducible example. There are many strings to iterate through in list 1. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element of the `keyword_list` list, verify that the `set` of words is a subset of the `set` of a target, and sum for each target

```
keyword_list = ["nike shoes", "airmax shoes"]
target_keyword_list = ["nike shoes", "shoes nike", "nike airmax shoes"]

check_list = []
for keywords in keyword_list:
    check_list.append(
        sum(set(keywords.split()).issubset(target.split())
            for target in target_keyword_list)
    )

print(check_list)  # [3, 1]
```

---

Could be easier to get it with a more verbose syntax

```
check_list = []
for keywords in keyword_list:
    ks = set(keywords.split())
    count = 0
    for target in target_keyword_list:
        count += ks.issubset(target.split())
    check_list.append(count)
```

Comment: This will however not match the full word. For example, "air shoes max" will  match "airmax shoes".

Comment: @not_speshal not with the `size` word, bu I get is, I've edited

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `set` `difference`:

```
check_list = list()
for keyword in keyword_list:
    check_list.append(len([t for t in target_keyword_list if not set(keyword.split()).difference(set(t.split()))]))
```

Comment: `sum([1 for t in target_keyword_list if not set(keyword.split()).difference(sett.split())])`

Answer (score 0):

So each keyword is actually a sequence of spaced words, each of which must be present for it to be a match?

This is how I would do it. The list comprehension is kinda pushing the limit for how big I like them to be, and I would be tempted to just break it out into a regular for loop, but since you had one I kept one.

```
keyword_list = ["nike shoes", "puma shoes", "nike sneakers", "puma sneakers"]
target_keyword_list = ["nike shoes", "shoes nike", "nike airmax shoes", "puma sneakers"]

check_list = []
for keyword in keyword_list:
    check_freq = sum(all(part in target_keyword for part in keyword.split(' ')) for target_keyword in target_keyword_list)
    check_list.append(check_freq)
```

> [3, 0, 0, 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` intersection

```
keyword_list = ["nike shoes"]
target_keyword_list = ["nike shoes", "shoes nike",'jack nike', "nike airmax shoes",'shoes for jim']


check_list = {}
for keyword in keyword_list:
    temp0 = set(keyword.split())
    for target in target_keyword_list:
        temp1 = set(target.split())
        intersection = temp0 & temp1
        found = temp0 == intersection
        check_list[target] = found
for k,v in check_list.items():
  print(f'{k} --> {v}')
```

output

```
nike shoes --> True
shoes nike --> True
jack nike --> False
nike airmax shoes --> True
shoes for jim --> False
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you are trying to see how many combinations there are in `target_keyword_list` that have at least one word from each key in `keyword_list`.

For that you'd have to first separate strings into separate words, you can do that with `.split()` string method:

```
for kw_item in keyword_list:
    words = kw_item.split()
    # ['nike', 'shoes']
```

Then go through the second list and check if each key has at least one word from the `words`. If you only want to check for same letter combinations, you can simply check each each `word` against each string in `target_keyword_list`:

```
for t_item in target_keyword_list:
    if word in t_item:
        count += 1
```

And then add count to the result before going to the next item in `kw_items`.

If the idea is to check for each separate word (consider *shoe* and *shoes* different words), then you'll have to also split every string in `target_keyword_list` and run a direct comparison between each word in those dictionaries.

```
for t_item in target_keyword_list:
    t_words = t_item.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in t_words:
        count += 1
```

This is not the most elegant or short logic but it's easy to understand and apply to different situations, in case you need a slightly different solution. Also, once you understand how it works, you can shorten `for in` and `if` constructions into oneliners.

Comment: You solution is good, but it should be improved to fit conditions. You need to validate that all words from `keyword_list` item exist in `target_keyword_list` item and if condition met increment `count`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I gave the answer with assumption that whoever reads it, at least is familiar with the concept of counting within a loop. It's something any aspiring developer has to recognize as they learn how to work with loops.
The goal was not to provide a working solution right away but instead to explain logic to follow when dealing with such tasks.